# No row message for more than one tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I created four tablixes for my report.  if at least one tablix has no data, I would like to show 'no row message' and no data for other tablixes. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote No row message for only one tablix, and i wrote the following condition for visibility for all tablixes .

```
=IIF((countrows("Dataset1") = 0
AND countrows("Dataset2") = 0
AND countrows("Dataset3") = 0
AND countrows("Dataset4") = 0)
,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requeriment. I ended up creating a dataset that checks if the report datasets return rows.

You only have to create a textbox with the message `No rows` then use the dataset that checks for rows in the report datasets and based on the data returned hide the textbox and show your tablix, or show the textbox and hide your tablix.

Let me know if this helps.